# How to delete column name

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete to just column name (x,y,z), and use only data.

```
In [68]: df
Out[68]: 
   x  y  z
0  1  0  1  
1  2  0  0 
2  2  1  1 
3  2  0  1 
4  2  1  0
```

I want to print result to same as below.

```
Out[68]: 

0  1  0  1  
1  2  0  0 
2  2  1  1 
3  2  0  1 
4  2  1  0
```

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In pandas by default need column names.

But if really want `'remove'` columns what is strongly not recommended, because get duplicated column names is possible assign empty strings:

```
df.columns = [''] * len(df.columns)
```

---

But if need write `df` to file without columns and index add parameter `header=False` and `index=False` to [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', header=False, index=False)

df.to_excel('file.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: wow! header=false..  so i appreciate it! i want to know about it !!

Comment: So you need remove column names because need write to file without them?

Comment: right .. i want to write data without columnname and index.

Comment: @jezrael how to keep the 1st dataframe columns names and remove the next dataframe column names in to_excel?

Comment: @dondapati - Not sure if understand, can you explain more?

Comment: @ jezrael ,using the for loop i created multiple dataframes ,here column names are same for all dataframes  .now i want keep 1st dataframe column as reference for all dataframes. and export in to excel.

Comment: @dondapati - hmmm, so I suggest use `for i, df in enumerate(dfs):` and if `i == 1` then save columns names, if `i > 0` not.

Answer (score 12):

If all you need is to print out without the headers then you can use the `to_string()` and set `header=False`, e.g.:

```
>>> print(df.to_string(header=False))
0  1  0  1
1  2  0  0
2  2  1  1
3  2  0  1
4  2  1  0
```

Answer (score 9):

If you need to remove the header alone, uses '.values'.

```
df = df[:].values
```

But the above code will return a numpy array instead of dataframe. Converting the same again into dataframe will add default values to column names (0,1..).

Comment: this work perectly!! It is a shame that a command like df.rename(columns=None) or similar doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

First find the number of columns by:

```
df.shape  # it helps you to know the total no of columns you have (as well as rows)
```

Lets say shape is `(188,8)`:

```
df.columns = np.arange(8)  #here we have `8` columns
```

This makes the columns as int64 starting from 0 to 7 .

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
df.name = None
```

Comment: This does not delete the column but assigns `None` all rows in column `name`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This is wrong, please delete it