# AttributeError: can't delete attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had this data frame `df1`

```
              Type  Count
0  Entire home/apt   5326
1       Hotel room    249
2     Private room   5570
3      Shared room    628
```

After transposing `df1`, the transposed data frame `df2` looked like this

```
df2 = df1.T
df2 .columns = df2 .iloc[0]
df2 = df2 [1:]

print(df2.index)
Out: Index(['Count'], dtype='object')

print(df2.columns)
Out: Index(['Entire home/apt', 'Hotel room', 'Private room', 'Shared room'], dtype='object', name='Type')

print(df2)
Out:
Type    Entire home/apt Hotel room  Private room    Shared room
Count   5326            249         5570            628
```

I wanted to obtain a desired data frame that should look like this (where the heading `Type` disappeared)

```
        Entire home/apt Hotel room  Private room    Shared room
Count   5326            249         5570            628
```

by using this code to remove `Type` from the columns name

```
del df2.columns.name
```

However, it resulted in an error `AttributeError: can't delete attribute`

Could someone please explain what that meant and how to resolve it to obtain the desired data frame?

Thank you.

**Edit**: please note, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917675/pandas-delete-column-name) didn't address my question as it removed the **names/headings** of the columns. I only wanted to remove the *attribute name* (in this case `Type`) of the columns name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df2 = df2.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917675/pandas-delete-column-name).

Pandas by default **needs** column names.

So you could do something like this to hide it

```py
df2.rename(columns={'Type': ''}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But renaming `Type` to *blank* still leaves *something* there, preventing me to graph it with `streamlit.bar_chart(df2)`

Comment: Oh if you are planning to plot it further you could just say 'Type' : None?

Answer (score 0):

if this doesn't work:  del df2.index.name

You can run this:  df2.index.name = None

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
df2.columns.name = None

df2.index.name = None
```

Try this code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).